# Ends and coends in 2-categories and the twisted arrow 2-category

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory

> Note before we begin: 2-category here means some model for 2-categories that is sufficiently nicely behaved homotopically. You can use some fragment of the $(\infty,2)$-version of the theory or use bicategories.  Knock yourself out.

### The classical version

There's a well-known trick due I think to Mac Lane where one can compute ends and coends of Set-valued bifunctors using the twisted arrow category:

First, a bifunctor $$B:C\times C^{\operatorname{op}} \to \mathbf{Set}$$ can also be expressed as a discrete opfibration $$E(B)\to C\times C^{\operatorname{op}}$$ by the simplest form of the Grothendieck construction.  Then we have the discrete fibration $$\pi_C:\operatorname{TwArr}(C)\to C\times C^{\operatorname{op}}$$ corresponding to the $\operatorname{Hom}$ bifunctor.

Then given some other bifunctor $B^\prime:C\times C^{\operatorname{op}}\to \mathbf{Set}$, we can precompose with $\pi_C$ and form the colimit in the category of sets.

It turns out that if you unwind all of this stuff that this colimit actually computes the *coend* of $B^\prime$.  This is the main ingredient in the theorem that for ordinary (that is to say set-enriched) categories,  existence of all conical colimits implies the existence of all weighted colimits as well, since weighted colimits can be computed by coends, and coends can be computed as special conical colimits.

### Once more; this time with feeling

It turns out that there is a 2-categorical version of the twisted arrow category.  It's a bit harder to construct, but it is similarly the Grothendieck construction of the $\operatorname{Hom}$-(2)-bifunctor.

Here's a picture of a simple but nontrivial case, the twisted arrows of the 2-Disk:

[Twisted 2-arrows of the 2-disk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erb6Q.png)

Anyway, in enriched category theory generally, and in the theory of 2-categories in particular, it has been known for quite some time that the existence of conical colimits does not imply the existence of all weighted limits (explicit counterexamples were found decades ago).

> Edit:
> **I was taking a look at Kelly's book, which is where this information comes from, and I'm now less convinced by it.**
>
> In the [book](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/10/tr10.pdf), §3.9, Kelly says that unlike in the case of sets, the comparison map $$\operatorname{colim}(\operatorname{El}(VF_0)\to K^{\operatorname{op}}_0 \to [K,V]_0)\to F$$ is not generally an equivalence when $F$ is a $V$-valued diagram.
>
> However, in this case, we're not using the ordinary category of elements, but a true category of elements construction extending the ordinary Grothendieck construction.  That is to say, we're looking at the comparison functor $$\operatorname{colim}(\operatorname{El}_2(F)\to K^{\operatorname{op}}\to [K,\mathbf{Cat}])\to F$$
> At the very least, this menans that Kelly's note about the inadequacy of conical colimits here doesn't really apply, since we're using an enhanced construction from the outset.
>
> Is it possible, then, that this actually works after all and every 2-category is also the conical colimit in a natural way of a single diagram of representable diagrams?
>
> One thing that worries me a bit is that with all of these enriched gadgets in play is the possibility that the comparison map might not even exist (specifically, is it even obvous that $F$ is even a cone for that diagram, or is it possibly only a lax cone or something stupid like that.

But at any rate, back to coends, we have this beautiful gadget of twisted 2-arrows $$\pi_C:\operatorname{Tw}^\ell_2(C)\to C\times C^{\operatorname{op}}.$$  So then what happens if you compute (2)-colimit of the functor $$B\circ \pi_C:\operatorname{Tw}^\ell_2(C) \to \mathbf{Cat}?$$

Does it still compute the coend?  If that's the case, what is so special about $\mathbf{Cat}$?  Is it the case that twisted arrows here work well enough because $\mathbf{Cat}$ already has tensors, and the 'bad' weighted colimits are exclusively the tensors?

If it doesn't compute the coend, what does it compute, and can we do something more sophisticated than simply taking a colimit to recover the actual coend?

Answer (score 3):

A few remarks that wouldn't fit a comment.

1. The fact that $\int^c B'\cong \varinjlim (B'\circ \pi_C)$ is of course true even if $B'$ codomain is not $\bf Set$ but a generic other category $D$.
2. The question of whether one can have a "category of elements" construction in bases of enrichment different from $\bf Set$ is a subtle matter; for quite some time, the best we have available was https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.03829, but I think new ideas are in the the recently appeared https://arxiv.org/abs/2302.04566
3. If I had your same question I would try to build some intuition on $Tw_2^\ell(C)$ in simple cases, and then compute a 2-colimit of $B'\circ \pi_{C,2}$ when $B'$ is mute in the co/contra-variant component; then fix two 2-functors $F,G : C\to D$ and compute for $B'=\hom(F,G)$; then take a pseudofunctor $H : C \to \bf Cat$ and fix $B'_X(\__1, \__2):= H(\__2)\times C(\__1,X)$; then take a *lax* functor and compute the same. Do you get $HX$ back in the first case? How far do you fall from $HX$ in the second case (you can't get $H$ back if it was genuinely lax, because $B'_X$ is a pseudofunctor in $X$: see [¹] below.)?
4. The mathematical production of Syméon Bozapalides is a goldmine (and the only existing reference) for the theory of 2-dimensional coends. See in particular (but not limited to these papers)

   - Bozapalidès, Syméon. "Some remarks on lax-presheafs." Illinois Journal of Mathematics 24.4 (1980): 676-680. [¹] This is the paper that measures how far $Hx$ and $\int^c Hc\times C(c,x)$ are.
   - _. "Les fins cartésiennes généralisées." Archivum Mathematicum 13.2 (1977): 75-87.
   - _. "A note on 2-distributors." Journal of the Australian Mathematical Society 23.2 (1977): 242-246.
   - _. "Sur les quasi-limites." Cahiers de topologie et géométrie différentielle catégoriques 17.3 (1976): 235-260.
   - _. "Les bimodules rélatifs." Archivum Mathematicum 13.3 (1977): 125-134.

   In addition, Guitart, Van den Bril et al., explored, in the 1970s, the notion of lax co/end in connection with categorifications of the bicategory of profunctors; see here http://rene.guitart.pagesperso-orange.fr/textespublications/rg30.pdf but by all means refer to more modern sources (K. Hirata recently published a note on lax ends https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.01522 although there is no reference to Guitart's work.)
5. I am starring the thread because I'm very curious to see the answer to your question. Definitely keep me posted.

Comment: I've convinced myself now that using the higher category of elements to replace the classical one makes this work.  Working on a proof now.  You can think of it like this: $\mathbf{Cat}_n$ has a kind of weighted colimit-coclassifier given by the higher category of elements.